# Swift 2.0 locationManager refreshes view but wont stay still once the view has loaded

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I'm working on an app that shows only annotations within a 30 mile radius.  I can get that part to work. And on loading, it zooms down into the current location.  I can zoom in/out, but within a few seconds if not immediately it zooms back to its original region view.

I've scoured the internet and this site for solutions, but none have been adequate.  My code below does not include the annotations but does replicate the problem I am having.

one suggestion I found was to use `locationManager.requestLocation` instead of `.startUpdatingLocations` but that just makes it crash.

```
import MapKit
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate,         CLLocationManagerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLoction: CLLocation = locations[0]
    let latitude = userLoction.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = userLoction.coordinate.longitude
    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Every time the location changes `didUpdateLocations` will be called, if the distance is at least that specifed for `distanceFilter`. Since you haven't set this, it will be the default of `kCLDistanceFilterNone`. This means every slight change will cause the function to be called, and that code resets the region with `setRegion`.

You could use `distanceFilter` to only reset the region if the location changes substantially, and/or detect that the user has zoomed the screen, and use the current 'span' rather than resetting it to (0.05, 0.05).

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try.  Can you edit my code with your suggestion so that I can compare when I'm done?